# How do I change a toilet water supply line that doesn’t have a shut off valve?

Tags: toilet

[image]

The washer has corroded but this supply line just goes straight into the wall. There is no shut off valve so I can’t just unscrew and replace it.  Any easy fix?

Comment: Turn off the main.

Comment: You'd probably want to install a shutoff valve while you're at it.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. If there's no shutoff, why isn't water spouting out of that end? And, if water isn't spouting out of that end, what's the problem?

Comment: `I can’t just unscrew` ... you already did .... any other silly questions?

Comment: I guess I didn’t explain myself clearly.  I know how to turn the water off.  I’m asking how I change the fixture I’m holding in my hand which is just a tube that goes into the wall.  Most toilets have a shut off valve that this piece is connected to so you just screw and unscrew it.  Since this tube just goes directly into the wall I was asking how I can replace it.  All the videos I’ve seen show a fixture with a shut off valve.

Comment: It amazes me the rude comments.  Do people really have that much time on their hands to be so obnoxious? It’s a simple question really, just trying to get some help for a diy project which I thought that’s what this site was for.

Comment: Post a wider angle photo please. So terminology is focusing with your question vs photo. Supply lines come out of walls and floors, if they have a shutoff valve, then a box to the toilet, are you looking to replace the hose? If you shut the water off, how or where? You can cut supply lines and use a sharkbite fitting to add a vale of you are missing a shutoff valve.